# Parse does not send http requests encrypted

Tags: android, http, parse-platform

When using my app hackers can intercept the http request sent from my app to the parse server as seen in the method describred below. Why does parse not encrypt data? and how can i send it encrypted?

When I created an account when I first opened the app, I captured the HTTP request it sent, than I replayed the request and edited the 'satoshi' part to however many satoshis I would want, changed the username so it would register
{"password":"passwordsarefun","device_id":"1111111 1111111111","tampered":false,"totalSatoshi":0,"use rname":"SoAreUsernames","satoshi":9999999999999999 ,"emailAddress0":"emails@arentas.fun","dailyReward ":0}
Than all you have to do is login and withdraw

Comment: I never used parse.com but I would guess you need to use https instead if http to get encryption ;-)

Comment: That i agree with but i need to know how to do that with parse

Comment: With what program and on what device did you capture the data?

Comment: I have an android app that uses parse to manage users and points